# Depend on a Visual Studio project in CMake

Tags: windows, visual-studio, cmake

My project is using CMake and I want to depend on another project (a library) which is only available as a Visual Studio project (no CMakeLists.txt). While I could add the dependency by hand after generating my project, I was looking for a way do that in my CMakeLists.txt so I don't have to do it every time?

I know I could also just build the library and link the result, but I would prefer to avoid that so that the resulting Visual Studio project will easily work for all architectures.

(I'm fine with having Visual Studio as the only working Generator)

Comment: Why not write a CMake file for the Visual Studio library project?

Comment: Because there are actually two projects I need to depend on and one of them is huge. Therefore it would be a lot of work and it might actually be easier to write a Visual Studio project for my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: [`include_external_msproject`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/include_external_msproject.html)